# How to transform attribute-access to inherited attribute-access in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have some classes in python that inherit from a super class. The super class has a dictionary with some values in it. Some of the derived classes use this dictionary directly via attribute-access. Some of the derived classes however define their own dictionary, overwriting the dictionary of the super class.

This creates an all-or-nothing situation where the classes can either inherit the dictionary attribute from the super class or replace it for themselves with their own.

Is there a backwards-compatible, -prefereable pythonistic- way to let the clases inherit the dictionary of the parent and augmenting it with their own entries? If everything were accessed with methods I would just do something in the inherited classes like so:

```
class SuperClass(object):
   my_dict = {'key': 'value'}
   def get_dictioary(self):
        return my_dict

class Inherited(SuperClass):
    my_dict = {'some key': 'some value'}
    def get_dictionary(self):
        dictionary = super(SuperClass, self).get_dictioary().copy()
        dictionary.update(my_dict)
        return dictionary
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but I think you could just "break out" the my_dict into class attributes.

Comment: also since `my_dict` is a staticproperty you don't have to call super, you can just access it `SuperClass.my_dict`

Answer (score 1):

your subclass coudl take a dictionary when it is instantiated

```
class Inherited(SuperClass):
   my_dict = {}
   def __init__(self, a_dict):
      # get Superclasses dict
      Inherited.my_dict = SuperClass.my_dict
      # update with child class specific values
      Inherited.my_dict.update(a_dict)


in = Inherited({'some key': 'some value'})
in.my_dict #Inherited.my_dict
# {'key': 'value', 'some key': 'some value'}
```